# jquery focus() is not working on input, trying to check wearther input is clicked, waiting for typimg, or not

Tags: jquery, html, css

I try to check input if it is clicked and waiting for typing or not. I am using jquery is() function but the hovering effect doesn't work with mouseover(), mouseout(). also I've done a bit of empty check using also focusin() , focusout()-looks working. I was thinking to use focuse thing with css. the jquery version is not working, it skips first part (I put green color for hovering.). can I get help in this matter? I don't understand, why does it skips the green colored part. 
my code is 
also a link

[codepen: loginformbs3](https://codepen.io/cfrank2000/pen/ExjmZEp)

```
if ($(".form-group").find("#pwd").is(":focus")) {
    $(".form-group").find("#pwd").mouseover(function(){
        $(".form-group").find("#pwd").css("background-color", "green");
      });
      $(".form-group").mouseout(function(){
        $(".form-group").css("background-color", "pink");
      });
      } else {
        $(".inputbox").mouseover(function(){
        $(this).css("background-color", "lightblue");
      });
      $(".inputbox").mouseout(function(){
        $(this).css("background-color", "white");
      });
}
```

Comment: You're checking whether the element is focused when the page loads, not when the event happens. The `if` statement should be inside the event handler, not outside.

Comment: why if(is(':focus')... ? why not [$('.container').on('focus','element',function() .... ]. It's   better to organize your CSS like by adding a class for error and a class for success. Then your code would be clearer,  easier to update and then you can optimize it by toggleClass() based on conditions... would you like a snippet just for that part?

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understood your expected effects. This method toggles predefined Css classes based on focus event.
As you didn't explained the Onfocusout part, I'm just toggling the inputbox element' class based on the password focus' status.

Please [Notice] the Css classes .focused and .inpBox added here following the script logic.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
      var fg=$(".form-group");
      var pwd=$(".form-group #pwd");
      pwd.on('focus',function(){
          $(this).toggleClass('focused');
          console.log('focused');
      });
      $(".inputbox").toggleClass('inpBox',(pwd.not(':focus')));
      });
```

```css
.form-control{
     margin-top:15px;
     margin-bottom:5px;
   }
      .box {
        position: relative;
  
      }
      .inputsize {
        position: relative;
        width: calc( 100% - 25px);
  left: 25px;
        background-color: transparent;
  z-index:1;
      }
      .inputglyph {
        position: absolute;
        left: 6px;
        top: 10px;
        color: darkred;
      }
      .inputbox {
        position: relative;
        width: calc(100% - 2px);
        height: 100%;
        /*  background-color:yellow;*/
      }
      .warning {
        color: red;
      }
      .ok {
        color: green;
      }
      .inputstatus {
        position: static;
        background: white;
      }
      .feedback {
        float: right;
        right: 4px;
      }
      .star {
        float: left;
        left: 6px;
        color: green;
      }
      .error {
        position: relative;
        left: 12px;
      }
      .float {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 2px;
        left: 42px;
        color: gray;
      }
      .up {
        color: "green";
        bottom: "38px";
        left: "32px";
      }
      .email_placehold {
        position: absolute;
        top: 8px;
        left: 94px;
        color: cyan;
  z-index:0;
      }
      .pw_placehold {
        position: absolute;
        top: 8px;
        left: 118px;
        color: cyan;
  z-index:0;
      }
.focused:not( :hover ){ 
background-color:pink;
}
.focused:hover{
background-color:green;
}
.inpBox:not( :hover ){
background-color:white;
}
.inpBox:hover{
background-color:lightblue;
}
```

```html
<link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <body>
    <p>Click this paragraph.</p>
    <h2>Vertical (basic) form</h2>
    <form>
      <div class="form-group">
        <div id="box1" class="box">
          <div class="inputbox" id="inpemail" >
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope inputglyph"></span>
            <input
              type="email"
              class="form-control inputsize check"
              id="email"
              placeholder=""
              name="E-mail"
            />
          </div>
          <label id="flemail" class="float" for="email">E-mail:</label>
          <span id="plemail" class="email_placehold">Like John.Doe@email.com</span>
        </div>
        <!--<span class="error">email</span>-->
        <!--<span class="error">name</span>-->

        <div id="inputstat1" class="inputstatus">
          <span id="" class="glyphicon  glyphicon-star star"></span>
          <span id="erroremail" class="error">Your email</span>
          <span id="errorfeedbk1" class="feedback"></span>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <div id="box2" class="box">
          <div class="inputbox" id="inppwd">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock inputglyph"></span>
            <input
              type="password"
              class="form-control inputsize check"
              id="pwd"
              placeholder=""
              name="Password"
            />
          </div>
          <label id="flpwd" class="float" for="pwd">Password:</label>
          <span id="plpwd" class="pw_placehold">Like Password123</span>
        </div>
        <!--<span class="error">password</span>-->
        <div id="inputstat2" class="inputstatus">
          <span class="glyphicon  glyphicon-star star"></span>
          <span id="errorpw" class="error">Your password</span>
          <span id="errorfeedbk2" class="feedback"></span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="checkbox">
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="remember" /> Remember me</label>
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn1">Submit</button>
    </form>
    
  </body>
```